# How to Get Cordova to Work With Android Studio?

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio

I have the newest everything, node, npm, android studio, cordova.

I created a new project with:

```
cordova create test
cd test
cordova platform add android
```

I go into Android Studio, import project, go to test/platforms/android it finds the build.gradle file, works on it for awhile then spits out:

```
Gradle version 1.10 is required. Current version is 2.2.1
```

So I go to my build.gradle file, and update the line

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.10.+'
    }
```

to:

```
 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.14.+'
    }
```

And then I re-import my project, it chugs on it for awhile, then spits out:

```
Error:failed to find Build Tools revision 19.0.0
```

So I install Build Tools 19.0.0

And it tells me:

```
Error:The SDK Build Tools revision (19.0.0) is too low for project 'android'. Minimum required is 19.1.0
```

So I look at my SDK Manager and I have 19.1.0 installed

So I go back into my build.gradle file:

and I change:

```
buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"
```

to

```
buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"
```

And re-import again,

And still tells me:
Error:The SDK Build Tools revision (19.0.0) is too low for project ':CordovaLib'. Minimum required is 19.1.0

I even try and delete SDK Build Tools revision 19, and keep 19.1 but it still tells me that.

Can anyone that has done this song and dance please help me?

Comment: right now it just doesn't work, cordova team is working on it, I think they solved the problem, but haven't released it yet. But, why do you wan't to use android studio? you don't need that

Comment: not sure. I was using eclipse just fine, but I noticed that android studio is google's preferred ide that they're now promoting over at http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Comment: But that is for native development, if you use cordova, and plan to develop for more platforms, use an editor like brackets or sublime and the cordova CLI to install plugins, run, deploy, etc.

Comment: interesting.. I thought that I needed the IDE so I can run/deploy/use simulator. have you deployed apps to the store with cordova cli alone?

Comment: @OliverJ90 too much of a hassle, I reverted to eclipse until they get their act together

Comment: @foreyez managed to get this working. Might be worth another look for you. Make sure to edit the gradle settings in the Cordova lib and reimport your project each time you fix an error.

Answer (score 7):

I had exactly the same problem and just fixed it. What you need to do is complete the same buildToolsVersion "19.1.0" change to the build.gradle file in the CordovaLib folder within your platform project folder e.g. platforms/android/CordovaLib.

Comment: Thanks! Worked here. I changed in build.gradle file, but there is another gradle file inside CordovaLib. I guess both files must be updated.

Comment: Same for me, Also modify `build.gradle` in `platforms/android/CordovaLib` helped me out!

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem, modifing gradle file App and gradle file CordovaLib, with the following information:

```
changed   dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0+'
    }
}
```

and

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"
}
```

*Tested on Android Studio 1.1*

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem. In the end choosing "Import Non-Android Studio project" and navigating to the android folder platforms/android worked. Wasn't sure if you initially choose the "Import Non-Android Studio project" option.

Comment: were you able to then edit and deploy the app to an emulator?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and corrected the content of build.gradle directly in Android Studio (replacing 19.0.0 with 19.1.0).  The build was succeful after that.  Of course, this is only a workaround until the Cordova team fixes the problem permanently. Good luck.